# what's the TableProps for dynamodb when using aws cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

I'm using aws cdk for dynamodb, wanna add a dynamodb table, already got this code, what's the TableProps for dynamodb? I thought it's table name with string type, but seems wrong, can anyone help me with that?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/aws-dynamodb/tableprops.html#aws_dynamodb_TableProps_tableName

```
import core = require('@aws-cdk/core');
import dynamodb = require('@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb')

export class HelloCdkStack extends core.Stack {
  constructor(scope: core.App, id: string, props?: core.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    new dynamodb.Table(this, 'MyFirstTable', {
        tableName: 'myTable'
      });
  }
}
```

This is the error

```
lib/dynamodb.ts:8:46 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ tableName: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TableProps'.
  Property 'partitionKey' is missing in type '{ tableName: string; }' but required in type 'TableProps'.

 8     new dynamodb.Table(this, 'MyFirstTable', {
                                                ~
 9         tableName: 'myTable'
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
10       });
   ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb/lib/table.d.ts:19:14
    19     readonly partitionKey: Attribute;
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'partitionKey' is declared here.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
import { AttributeType } from '@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb';

    new dynamodb.Table(this, 'MyFirstTable', {
      tableName: "myTable",
      partitionKey: {
            name: "MyPartitionkey,
            type: AttributeType.STRING
          }
    });
```

Comment: I have added import statement in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

TableProps extends TableOptions and "partionKey" is a required property for creating a table with `dynamodb.Table`. I think the aws CDK documentation could be more clear about how "TableOptions" is used by "TableProps".

`export interface TableProps extends TableOptions`

Under TableOptions in the "partionKey" section it says:

`readonly partitionKey: Attribute;`

Without a "?" mark between "partionKey" and the ":" it means this property is required.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/aws-dynamodb/tableoptions.html#aws_dynamodb_TableOptions_partitionKey